# Weibull distribution: Is it possible to solve for the shape and scale from the mean?

Tags: weibull-distribution

I'm modeling product lifetimes. If I know what I want the average lifetime of a product in my model to be, is it possible to fit a Weibull distribution to only that data point?

Comment: nah: since you want two parameters out, you gotta put two parameters in.

Comment: To expand on @JohnMadden's comment: The [Weibull distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution) has two parameters, scale $\lambda$ and shape$k$ , and the mean depends on these two parameters: mean = $\mu = \lambda \, \Gamma(1+1/k)$. If you only know $\mu$, you will find tons of solutions for $k$ and $\lambda$.